# UIImage.Orientation always returning Up after upgrading to iOS 13.2.2

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin.Forms application when run on iOS, I have run into an issue where the UIImage.Orientation is always returning Up on iOS 13.2.2 regardless of the orientation the phone is held while the photo is captured, however on iOS 13.1.3 the orientation is returned as Right, Up or Left inline with how the phone is held.

Has anyone run into this issue and if so how did you resolve this? Is this a bug in iOS 13.2.2?

Comment: Which framework did you use? MediaPlugin or something other ? Maybe the plugin didn't update its source code after iOS updated to 13.2.x . And you can provide a sample which contains the issue and I will test it on my side .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT It looks like I am running into the issue reported here : https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/issues/760

Comment: So the issue has nothing to do with Xamarin.forms , and you can focus on it .